# Вывод уникальных лицевых счетов и суммирование оплат по этим значениям

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Есть таблица с двумя столбцами - лиц. счет и оплата. Некоторые лиц. счета повторяются (произведены оплаты несколько раз).

Нужно вывести список лиц. счетов без повторений и общие суммы оплат по этим счетам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в конце чего должно выводиться?

Comment: Можно чтобы такие лиц счета вообще в отдельной колонне с просуммированной оплатой выводились

Comment: Сводная таблица в помощь...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Извлекаем лицевые счета в столбец D:

```
=ЕСЛИ(D1=0;;ИНДЕКС(A:A;МИН(ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ($D$1:D1;$A$2:$A$20);"";СТРОКА($A$2:$A$20)))))
```

Формула массива, вводится сочетанием клавиш `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

Суммы оплат:

```
=СУММЕСЛИ(A:A;D2;B:B)
```

Ячейки с формулами копируем в строки ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

'-------------------------------

Если задача разовая, счета можно отобрать без формулы массива (но формула суммирования все же будет нужна).

Копировать лиц. счета, вставить в свободный диапазон. Не снимая выделения - закладка *Данные - Удалить дубликаты*.

'-------------------------------

Вариант макросом. Код разместить в общем модуле.

```
Sub SumUniq()
Dim aData()
Dim dSum As Double, sAcc As String
Dim i As Long, k As Long, n As Long
    With Worksheets("Лист1")
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        aData = .Range("A1:B" & i).Value
        k = 1

        For i = 2 To UBound(aData)
            If aData(i, 1) <> Empty Then
                dSum = 0: sAcc = aData(i, 1)

                For n = i To UBound(aData)
                    If aData(n, 1) = sAcc Then
                        dSum = dSum + aData(n, 2)
                        aData(n, 1) = Empty
                    End If
                Next n

                k = k + 1
                aData(k, 1) = sAcc: aData(k, 2) = dSum
            End If
        Next i

        .Range("D1").Resize(k, 2).Value = aData
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Получилось сделать с помощью консолидации.

Comment: Консолидация изменяет данные. Вряд ли это можно считать корректным решением...